# How can I stop my image from resizing when the soft keyboard appears?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a Windows 8 game where I have an `Image` whose `Source` is a Direct3D interop that acts as a gameboard. When the soft keyboard appears on the screen, I have the following code to prevent the standard behaviour of my view from being pushed up to accommodate the keyboard (It's desired that the gameboard stays in place when the keyboard appears):

```
private void KeyboardShowing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args) 
{
    double offSetHeight = args.OccludedRect.Height;
    ContainerGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, offsetHeight, 0, 0);
}
```

The code above is working for the other non-gameboard parts of page. However, the system is automatically resizing my image to fit in the visible portion of the screen. How can I stop this from happening?